# bind two rows with raw data to data frame in R

Tags: r

I try to bind new row with raw data into data frame and received one concatenated row.
Code:

```
dd = data.frame(readBin(f1, what=raw(), n=1e6));
colnames(dd) = c("dane");   
str(dd);
d1 = data.frame(readBin(f2, what=raw(), n=1e6));
dd = rbind(dd, d1);
str(dd);
```

Result:

```
'data.frame':   11737 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ dane: raw  89 50 4e 47 ...
'data.frame':   23474 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ dane: raw  89 50 4e 47 ...
```

Why I can't see two rows?

Comment: Your first obect has 11737 rows with 1 column, and your second object has 23474 rows with 1 column. That's what happen when you bind rows. Maybe you want to `readBin` to vectors and `rbind` the vectors? This will give you a raw matrix with two rows and 11737 columns.

Comment: It looks like proper solution. Result:
'data.frame': 2 obs. of  11737 variables:

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
    library(magrittr)
    dd = readBin(f1, what=raw(), n=1e6)
    d1 = readBin(f2, what=raw(), n=1e6)

    df = rbind(dd,d1) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't change the result.